# Android: 9-patch repeat pattern instead of stretching

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a 9-patch image file which looks like this:

[image]

When I use it it appears like this:

[image]

What I actually wanted to achieve is the complete dot in the center **repeated** instead of **stretched**. I hope that it's possible.

Comment: This would be very handy!  I just came across an issue where I needed this behavior!

Comment: This might help:
http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-have-tiled-background-cont.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it's not possible using 9-Patch to make repeated patterns (only stretching certain area), perhaps you could find more about it in official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)

Answer (score 15):

...

Correction: If you want the orange dots to repeat, you will not succeed using 9 patch. 9 patch can only stretch the part you told it to stretch and leave untouched, the remaining areas. There is no repeat mode with 9 patch PNG.

You might want to look into Bitmap class. There is a tileMode you might be able to use for your problem here.

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/stripe_bg"
            android:tileMode="repeat"
            android:antialias="true"
            android:dither="false"
            android:filter="false"
            android:gravity="left"
        />
```

Answer (score -4):

First make sure you save your 9 patch image as your_image_name.9.png and store it in the res/drawable folder. Then in your xml just set the layout background with-- android:background="@drawable/your_image_name" and that should work.  If it's still not working can you post your layout xml?

Comment: The 9-patch works (see above picture). But instead of stretching I'd like to have the pattern in the center repeated.