# 9 Patch Image is expanding vertically only instead of all directions ?

Tags: android, splash-screen, nine-patch

I am trying to create a splash screen with 9patchimage.... its working fine on a tablet device(2048*1536) but on the mobile device(1920x1080p) display image stretching vertically only
Here is my 9patch image [i am using this image for splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVhTb.png)

this one is the screenshot from mobile device
[here you can see its stretching vertically only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ecVa.png)

here is the XML layout of my splash screen file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splashscreen"
tools:context="app.av.com.app.gui.SplashScreen">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636251/android-9-patch-repeat-pattern-instead-of-stretching?rq=1

Comment: AdityaVyas-Lakhan the link you provided is not helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/splashscreen"
    tools:context="app.av.com.app.gui.SplashScreen">
```

But I think you should to use a png image with transparent background (remove green)in the middle of screen and `setBackgroundColor` to green in the all background

Comment: your answer is the simple and best method but i am stuck here with 9patchimages.... everyone behind screen knows this method but here the problem is 9patchimage not splash screen

Comment: Yeah, but if your screen have more height than your 9patchImage, always the image was deformed...(In my opinion), or maybe set a `imageView` inside your `FrameLayout` then you can "scale" your image to the all screen...@HarvinderSingh